# Read PDF Line By Line using iText7 and Fill on Textboxes Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I am working on a WinForms application. I use the pdf file to reset the password and the values on pdf are stored as key-value pairs(email: xxxx@mail.com, pass: 11111).

**What I want to do**:

Read the PDF file line by line and fill the appropriate textboxes.

**What I Have done**:

```
public bool CreatePDF(string location, string email, string key)
    {
        if(location != "" && email != "" && key != "")
        {
            PdfWriter pdfwriter = new PdfWriter(location);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfwriter);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);
            Paragraph fields = new Paragraph("Email: "+email + "\n" + "Secret Key: "+key);
            document.Add(fields);
            document.Close();
            return true;
        }            
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string ReadPDF(string location)
    {
        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(location));
        StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();
        var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        string text = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
        {
            var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
            text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
            processed.Append(text);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance Guys!. Any suggestions on CreatePDF are also welcome.

Comment: Consider splitting the result of `ReadPDF` at '\n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with,

```
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("G:\\Encryption_File.pdf"));
        StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();
        var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        string text = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
        {
            var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
            text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
            processed.Append(text);                
        }
        text.Split('\n');
        string line = "";                        
        line = text + "&";            
        string[] newLines = line.Split('&'); 
        textBox1.Text = newLines[0].Split(':')[1].ToString(); 
        textBox2.Text = newLines[0].Split(':')[2].ToString();
```